# Show that $A_n$ for $n>4$ is generated by the stabilizers from $1$ to $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, induction, stabilizer

**Question :** Show that $A_n$ for $n>4$ is generated by the stabilizers from $1$ to $n$.

**My Crude Thoughts :** I know that $A_n$ is generated by $3$ cycles. So I was thinking of expressing an element from the set generated by the stabilizers as a product of $3$ cycles and a $3$ cycle as an element from the set generated by the stabilizers. But I'm not sure if this is correct or how I can actually do this. I'm having trouble showing that a $3$ cycle is in the set generated by stabilizers.
Also, I thought of induction, the base case would be for $A_5$ and then assume the hypothesis for $n-1$. But I don't know how to prove the claim for $A_5$

**Edit :** Stabilizer from $1$ to $n$ means under the natural action of $A_n$ on the set $\{1,...,n\}$. Stabilizer of $1$ is the set of all elements from $A_n$ that fix $1$. And likewise for others elements from $\{1,...,n\}$.

Comment: "stabilizer form 1 to n"- what does it mean?

Comment: Under the natural action of $A_n$ on the set {1,...,n}. Stabilizer of 1 is the set of all elements from $A_n$ that fix 1. And likewise for others elements from {1,...,n}.

Comment: Why not do the case $n=4$ as well? After all $(123)$ stabilizes $4$.

Comment: Your idea about $3$-cycles works immediately. What's the problem?

Comment: I'm having trouble showing that a 3 cycle is in the set generated by stabilizers. Could you help with this?

Comment: This really should be clear. Think about it. What is a 3-cycle? What is a stabilizer?